# Re: Regex Question (Help)

Tags: regex

I am new here. I just discovered this tool "Everything Search Engine". It allows the use of regex in the search. I posted in their forum for a bit help here http://forum.voidtools.com/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=1343. This section explains how regex can be used in the tool http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#How_do_I_use_regex.

The question I am asking is:

What is the correct regex to use in the search to obtain the desired results describe below.

For example, I am searching for the word "dog" in the file name. And it returns a result "Pseudogout" which is a file name.

Notice the word "dog" is inside the word "Pseudogout".

How do I use the regex to eliminate such results?

I would appreciate some help here.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a example of filenames that you want to **include**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use anchors: `^dog$`. The caret matches the beginning of a string, and the dollar sign, the end.

If you want to match the string "dog" inside another string, but not inside another word, you might be able to use something like `^dog$|^dog[^A-Za-z]|[^A-Za-z]dog[^A-Za-z]|[^A-Za-z]dog$` but that is obviously somewhat cumbersome to type and use.

(This subsumes some information from the comments below.)

Comment: Hi Sebastion, I tested created a file "My dog 95.jpg" and tested with \bdog\b results is still negative. Is it possible the tool is restricted to these regex http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#How_do_I_use_regex ?

Comment: tripleee, I tried your suggestion and that did not yield any result.

Comment: Followed the link, looks like they support (or, at least, document) a fairly random subset of `egrep` regular expressions. If you're lucky, they have only forgotten to document some parts, in which case `\<dog\>` or at least `[^A-Za-z]dog[^A-Za-z]` might work (though the latter is not precisely right; it requires a character on both sides of the match. If they don't support caret and dollar, I don't really see how to search for exactly what you want).

Comment: Sorry, correction, it's basically traditional egrep syntax, so you can use ^a|a$|a to enumerate different matching alternatives, provided the target string is the file name ( and not, for example, a full path name).

Comment: Thanks triplee. I truly appreciate your time and help. I will contact them directly regarding the usage of regex in their search tool. Will let you know if I get this to work.

Comment: Thanks triplee. Your correction seems to do the job. I tried ^dogs|dogs$|dogs and seeing to desired results. I really do appreciate your help.

Comment: Please could you tag this question as answered then?  Thanks!

Comment: triplee, I have done as requested. Tagged as answered. Again, thank you.

Comment: triplee, if you are still around, how can I include a space inside the regex ^a|a$|a ? Like ^a |a $|a

Comment: Slightly cleaner would probably be: `(^|[^A-Za-z])dog($|[^A-Za-z])`.

Comment: Sebastian, that does not and will not work in the software command line. This ^a|a$|a works. The solution has to be close to that format.

Comment: In regex, a space is just a literal character. Perhaps you could post a new question if you cannot figure it out.